# Related post shortcode by post id

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I wrote following code for a shortcode displaying related post by post ID, something like this `[rpsid the_ID=2210]` should display post with id=2210, but it doesn't work. What's the problem? Thanks.

```
add_shortcode('rpsid', 'rp');

function rp( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( [
    'the_ID'      => '',
  ], $atts );

  $args = [ 'the_ID' => $atts['the_ID'] ];
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  ob_start();  ?>


      <div class="rps">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p>Also read:</p><span> <?php the_title(); ?></span></a>
      </div>

  <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: what happens if you var_dump($args)?

Comment: @Stender I don't know what should I do.

Comment: try to change the 'the_ID' ind $args to 'p'

Comment: meaning -> $args = [ 'p' => $atts['the_ID'] ];

Comment: @Stender Doesn't solve.

Comment: the 'p' Is how you query for a post by an ID - If it isn't returning anything, it means that there are no post with that ID in the post_type queried - Most likely your function rp() isn't understanding your the_ID. or the post isn't post_type post. try to hard code it - so  
$args = [ 'p' => '2210' ]; and see if it even adds a post? this way you might be able to understand where the error is

Comment: @Stender Yes you're right, the problem is `'p'`wants an integer but `$args` sends a string. Any idea how I can send it as integer?

Comment: $string = $atts['the_ID'];
$int = (int)$string;

Comment: @Stender Thank you very much it worked finally. Send it as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.